# Make CSS layout for responsive DIV grid

Tags: html, css

I need the CSS for a responsive DIV grid as seen in this layout.

[image]

This what I have made so far from the first answer which was a good starting point...

[image]

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="picture">
        <img class="picture" src="images/Ginger-004.jpg" width="300" alt="#">
    </div>
    <div class="text-container">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>CSS Layout for DIV Grid Puzzle</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <div>By Company Pty Ltd</div>
            <div>Type: Commercial</div>
            <div>Price: $295</div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <div><img src="images/buttons/home-page.jpg" border="0">  </div> 
            <div><img src="images/buttons/download.jpg" border="0"></div>
            <div><img src="images/buttons/buy-now.jpg" border="0"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>

.main-container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}
.header {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
.picture {
    padding: 10px;
}
.text-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr 1fr 4fr 1fr;
}
.buttons{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
    grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
    text-align: center;
}
button {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.message { 
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: justify;    
 }
```

But it is not responsive. It is not collapsing to fit a mobile phone screen.

Comment: Hold on a minute. We are bringing it!

Comment: https://grid.layoutit.com/ or https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.com/ or any from here https://www.creativebloq.com/features/5-cool-css-grid-generators

Comment: Create a container div to contain the whole section. Within it, set a left div to contain the image. then set a right div to contain the rest. within the right div, have heading div and below that is button div container. within btn div container, create 3 divs to hold 1 button each. then have a message div. reuse your button div below (use class). Done! Excellent answer by the great Mr Gosi <3

Comment: @Dave Anderson - I wasted 2 days messing with online CSS builders that do not work.

Comment: Why don't you post the code you have that doesn't work? We can help explain why it didn't work rather than just hand out a solution.

Comment: Who marks this question down and why?  It is perfectly clear... even has a pic to show EXPLICITY what is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to be responsive VIEWPORT needs to be added to the meta-tags. Then @media(min-width) needs to be added to the CSS.

```css
.main-container {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  display: grid;
}

.picture {
  height: 70%;
  width: 90%;
  background: #333;
  margin: 5%;
}

.image {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
}

.text-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 4fr 1fr;
}

.buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.message {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .main-container {
   grid-template-columns: 1fr;
   grid-template-areas: 
   "picture"
   "text-container"
  }
  
 }

 @media (min-width: 800px) {
  .main-container {
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
   grid-template-areas: 
   "picture text-container"
  }
  
 }
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="picture">
    <img class="image" src="#" alt="#">
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div><button>Button</button></div>
      <div><button>Button</button></div>
      <div><button>Button</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      <p>Message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div><button>Button</button></div>
      <div><button>Button</button></div>
      <div><button>Button</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks promising, but it is not responsive, ie: doesn't collapse to fit a mobile screen.

Comment: I had to remove all height settings because the grid was filling the page rater than cater for its contents only.

Comment: See my edited answer above, tldr - just add media queries using "grid-template-areas" on the main container.

Comment: I solved the problem of responsive by adding a viewport and @media(min-width: 600px)

Comment: The div with main-container class is going to determine the size of the whole element if any size is set for it, otherwise, yes remove the parent size and the child elements should set the size. As far as mobile, the media queries should do the trick. You can tweak the grid template areas and media queries as needed. You could also go even further depending on how you want the divs containing the buttons to collapse by adding queries for .buttons class with different definitions for grid-template-areas. Also, with this set-up, you will need to define a min-height: for the image element.

Comment: If I was able to help, please upvote! Also noticed in your code that you've updated from my original post, that you're using the same class for the image and it's parent container, which probably isn't what you meant to do, or maybe it is.. idk Good luck!